# Jenkins Console scripts to see % of time slaves spend running job in each day

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins

I'm writing a script to show how much time slaves spend to run various jobs each day.

I cannot seem to figure out the code which calculates the time spent by slaves to run jobs in 1 day.

I found builds.duration, but this looks like total time spend working since the slave was connected.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the exact answer, but it's a good start.  I wrote a groovy script years ago to get a bunch of information from the nodes here: [Node Information](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Display+Information+About+Nodes)

Here is the actual code, if the link ever dies:

```
for (aSlave in hudson.model.Hudson.instance.slaves) {
  println('====================');
  println('Name: ' + aSlave.name);
  println('getLabelString: ' + aSlave.getLabelString());
  println('getNumExectutors: ' + aSlave.getNumExecutors());
  println('getRemoteFS: ' + aSlave.getRemoteFS());
  println('getMode: ' + aSlave.getMode());
  println('getRootPath: ' + aSlave.getRootPath());
  println('getDescriptor: ' + aSlave.getDescriptor());
  println('getComputer: ' + aSlave.getComputer());
  println('\tcomputer.isAcceptingTasks: ' + aSlave.getComputer().isAcceptingTasks());
  println('\tcomputer.isLaunchSupported: ' + aSlave.getComputer().isLaunchSupported());
  println('\tcomputer.getConnectTime: ' + aSlave.getComputer().getConnectTime());
  println('\tcomputer.getDemandStartMilliseconds: ' + aSlave.getComputer().getDemandStartMilliseconds());
  println('\tcomputer.isOffline: ' + aSlave.getComputer().isOffline());
  println('\tcomputer.countBusy: ' + aSlave.getComputer().countBusy());
  //if (aSlave.name == 'NAME OF NODE TO DELETE') {
  //  println('Shutting down node!!!!');
  //  aSlave.getComputer().setTemporarilyOffline(true,null);
  //  aSlave.getComputer().doDoDelete();
  //}
  println('\tcomputer.getLog: ' + aSlave.getComputer().getLog());
  println('\tcomputer.getBuilds: ' + aSlave.getComputer().getBuilds());
}
```